# Installing same vb.net project in different versions

Tags: vb.net, versions

I do have a windows application (ex: application v1) running in server which I created in vb.net.
Now I need to have the same project with different name like Application_test in the same server. I copied the same project with different name and different assembly name and tried to build and install, it shows an error saying the **"Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/ Remove Programs on the control panel"**
 How to install same project's different versions in the same server?  Please help.

Comment: I assume you're using a setup project to create an MSI to install your application? If so it sounds like you haven't updated the name of the application in the setup project.

Comment: @ForkandBeard: Thanks for the reply. I tried renaming the name of vb project and the setup project.

Comment: Ok, but in the setup project there will be a property called something like 'Application name' (haven't got vs in front of me at the moment to be more specific). Have you changed that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to deployment project properties.
2. In the property window change the value against the property name Version to new value (ex: from 1.0.0 to 1.1.1).
3. It will prompt with a message box with this message `It is recommended that the productCode be changed if you change the Version. Do you want to do this?`. Click <kbd>YES</kbd>.
4. Build it and try installing the new version. This will work.